# Correct my use of BarChart labels

Tags: style, charts

I need to make a good bar chart based on the table below (the number of nodes with its probability of falling correspond to each **OF**):

[image: Table of data]

Thanks to **kglr** I got the necessary BarChart:

```
data14GAOF = {{33/36, 3/36}, {11/36, 25/36}, {27/36, 8/36, 
    1/36}, {14/36, 22/36}, {13/36, 10/36, 2/36, 1/36, 1/36, 1/36, 
    2/36, 4/36, 1/36, 1/36}, {8/36, 16/36, 8/36, 4/36}};
labels14GAOF = 
  Style[#, FontSize -> 18, White] & /@ {"node 4", "node 9", "node 7", 
    "node 3", "node 5", "node 6", "node 8", "node 10", "node 11", 
    "node 13"};
grouplabels14GAOF = 
  Style[#, Black, Bold, FontSize -> 18] & /@ {"OF1(N-1)", "OF1", 
    "OF2(N-1)", "OF2", "OF3(N-1)", "OF3"};
labeleddata14GAOF = 
  Labeled[##, Axis] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{SortBy[-First[#] &] /@ (MapIndexed[
          Labeled[#, labels14GAOF[[#2[[1]]]], Center] &, #] & /@ 
        data14GAOF), grouplabels14GAOF}];

BarChart[labeleddata14GAOF, 
 ChartStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.1], GrayLevel[0.2], GrayLevel[0.3], 
   GrayLevel[0.4], GrayLevel[0.5], GrayLevel[0.6], GrayLevel[0.65], 
   GrayLevel[0.7], GrayLevel[0.75], GrayLevel[0.8],}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> 900, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 24], BarSpacing -> {0, 0.8}]
```

But, unfortunately, I didn't take something into account and, as a result, BarChart looks like (there is a mismatch in the last column which I marked):

[image]

There is a strong likelihood that I chose inappropriate way to visualize and represent results.

Two questions

- What I have to do in order to get the right labels?
- How to make the columns closer to each other in accordance with the grouping (group OF1, group OF2, group OF3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way it can be done.

```
data14GAOF =
  {{33/36, 3/36},
   {11/36, 25/36},
   {27/36, 1/36, 8/36},
   {14/36, 22/36},
   {1/36, 13/36, 1/36, 1/36, 2/36, 2/36, 10/36, 4/36, 1/36, 1/36},
   {8/36, 8/36, 16/36, 4/36}};

labels14GAOF =
  {{"node 4", "node 9"},
   {"node 4", "node 9"},
   {"node 4", "node 7", "node 9"},
   {"node 4", "node 9"},
   {"node 3", "node 4", "node 5", "node 6", "node 7", 
    "node 8", "node 9", "node 10", "node 11", "node 13"},
   {"node 4", "node 5", "node 9", "node 11"}};

labeleddata14GAOF =
   MapThread[
     Labeled[#1, #2, Axis] &,
     {SortBy[-First[#] &] /@
        Apply[
          Labeled[#1, Style[#2, FontSize -> 16, White], Center] &, 
          Transpose /@ Transpose[{data14GAOF, labels14GAOF}],
          {2}],
      grouplabels14GAOF}];

BarChart[labeleddata14GAOF,
  ChartStyle ->
    {GrayLevel[0.1], GrayLevel[0.2], GrayLevel[0.3], GrayLevel[0.4], GrayLevel[0.5], 
     GrayLevel[0.6], GrayLevel[0.65], GrayLevel[0.7], GrayLevel[0.75], GrayLevel[0.8]},
   ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 24],
   BarSpacing -> {Automatic, .3}, 
   ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image: chart]

Notes

- The main change in strategy is in writing a list of the labels for each bar separately. I don't think trying to pick them out a common list of all node labels was a good idea; it is just too hard to get them right that way.
- It makes things easier to delay all the styling to label creation time.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question in accordance with your answer and met some difficulties.

Comment: @vladpopovcev. It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish by repeating yours bars multiple times. Besides, if you have new question because you modified your code, you should probably put it a new post, referencing this question as background.

Comment: I'm trying to represent the given results by means of barchart. Alright, I'll put my question in a new post and I'll try to find the appropriate way to describe that.