# Grouping of BarChart and BarChart labels

Tags: style, charts

Thanks to **m_goldberg** remarks [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191185/correct-my-use-of-barchart-labels), the following BarChart was obtained:

```
data14GAOF = {{33/36, 3/36}, {11/36, 25/36}, {27/36, 1/36, 
    8/36}, {14/36, 22/36}, {1/36, 13/36, 1/36, 1/36, 2/36, 2/36, 
    10/36, 4/36, 1/36, 1/36}, {8/36, 8/36, 16/36, 4/36}};
labels14GAOF = {{"node 4", "node 9"}, {"node 4", "node 9"}, {"node 4",
     "node 7", "node 9"}, {"node 4", "node 9"}, {"node 3", "node 4", 
    "node 5", "node 6", "node 7", "node 8", "node 9", "node 10", 
    "node 11", "node 13"}, {"node 4", "node 5", "node 9", "node 11"}};
grouplabels14GAOF = 
  Style[#, Black, Bold, FontSize -> 18] & /@ {"OF1(N-1)", "OF1", 
    "OF2(N-1)", "OF2", "OF3(N-1)", "OF3"};
labeleddata14GAOF = 
  MapThread[
   Labeled[#1, #2, Axis] &, {SortBy[-First[#] &] /@ 
     Apply[Labeled[#1, Style[#2, FontSize -> 16, White], Center] &, 
      Transpose /@ Transpose[{data14GAOF, labels14GAOF}], {2}], 
    grouplabels14GAOF}];
BarChart[labeleddata14GAOF, 
 ChartStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.1], GrayLevel[0.2], GrayLevel[0.3], 
   GrayLevel[0.4], GrayLevel[0.5], GrayLevel[0.6], GrayLevel[0.65], 
   GrayLevel[0.7], GrayLevel[0.75], GrayLevel[0.8]}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 24], 
 BarSpacing -> {Automatic, .3}, ImageSize -> 1200]
```

[image]

It is correct but it would be better to sowehow group the columns. In other words to separate each two columns OF1(N-1) and OF1, OF2(N-1) and OF2, OF3(N-1) and OF3 from each other a bit because they represent different functions. The idea is to get something like that:

[image]

How can it be realised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately `BarChart` does not support mixing different layouts.

To get the desired result, you can group the input data and use `BarChart` for each group, and combine the graphics primitives using `Translate`:

```
groups = Partition[labeleddata14GAOF, 2]; 
grouplabels = Style[#, 18, Bold] & /@ {"GA", "MOPSO", "NSGA"};
options = Sequence[ChartStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.1], GrayLevel[0.2], 
     GrayLevel[0.3], GrayLevel[0.4], GrayLevel[0.5], GrayLevel[0.6], 
     GrayLevel[0.65], GrayLevel[0.7], GrayLevel[0.75], 
     GrayLevel[0.8]}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 24], BarSpacing -> {Automatic, .3}];

bcs = BarChart[Labeled[##], options] /. Line[{{_, 0.}, {_, 0.}}] :> {} & @@@ 
  Transpose[{groups, grouplabels}]

groupspacing = .2;
Graphics[MapIndexed[Translate[#[[1]], {(2 + groupspacing) (#2[[1]] - 1), 0}] &, bcs], 
 AxesOrigin -> {0.5 - groupspacing, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.5 - groupspacing, 6.5 + 2 groupspacing}, All}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 Ticks -> {None, Automatic}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

With `groupspacing = .5;` we get

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is to use [`Invisible`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Invisible.html) and then "splice" an invisible bar into the data with [`Riffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html). Since the labeling is already rather "elaborate" and local, I have added some labeling now by hand for looks:

```
With[
  {
    groupLabelPosY = -0.06,
    barLabelPosY = -0.02,
    groupLabelStyle = Curry[Style, {3, 1, 2}]["Section"][Black],
    barLabelStyle = Curry[Style, {3, 1, 2}]["Subsection"][Black]
  }
  ,
  BarChart[ Evaluate@(labeleddata14GAOF // Riffle[ #, Invisible @ 0, 3] &)
    , ChartStyle -> {
        GrayLevel[0.1], GrayLevel[0.2], GrayLevel[0.3], GrayLevel[0.4],\
        GrayLevel[0.5], GrayLevel[0.6], GrayLevel[0.65], GrayLevel[0.7],\
        GrayLevel[0.75], GrayLevel[0.8]
      }
    , ChartLayout -> "Stacked"
    , AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 24]
    , BarSpacing -> {Automatic, .3}
    , ImageSize -> 1200
    , PlotRange -> {All, {-0.05, 1}}
    , Axes -> {False, True}
    , Epilog -> {
        Black
        , Line@{{0.4, 0}, {9, 0}}
        , Text[groupLabelStyle @ "GA", {1.5, groupLabelPosY}]
        , Text[groupLabelStyle @ "MOPSO", {4.5, groupLabelPosY}]
        , Text[groupLabelStyle @ "NSGA", {7.5, groupLabelPosY}]
        , Text[barLabelStyle @ "OF1(N-1)", {1, barLabelPosY}]
        , Text[barLabelStyle @ "OF1", {2, barLabelPosY}]
        , Text[barLabelStyle @ "OF2(N-1)", {4, barLabelPosY}]
        , Text[barLabelStyle @ "OF2", {5, barLabelPosY}]
        , Text[barLabelStyle @ "OF3(N-1)", {7, barLabelPosY}]
        , Text[barLabelStyle @ "OF3", {8, barLabelPosY}]
      }
  ]
]
```

[image: BarChart with Spacing and Group Labels]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I've never thought about usefulness of the `Invisible` function.